# Add method in LinkedList is not working

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm working on this as extra practice for my Java class but I can't seem to see why my add method is not working. I've tried walking through the code with the debugger line by line but I can't see where it's going wrong. It obviously a logic error. When I test the add method it seem to work but it's not linking the Node's correctly I guess, or not storing the data.

So the assignment is to write a linked-list (that does not add duplicates). I did the Node class as an inner function to the LinkedSet class. Our textbook suggested that for this particular assignment.
This is the add method I'm using.

```
public class LinkedSet <T> implements SetInterface <T> {    
        private Node firstNode;
        private int numberOfEntries;


        public LinkedSet (){
            firstNode = null;
            numberOfEntries = 0;
        }

    public boolean add(T newEntry){
                boolean result = false;
                Node aNewNode = new Node (newEntry);

                //If Node is currently null then add data to front
                if(firstNode == null)
                    firstNode = aNewNode;
                else
                {
                    //Add newEntry if it's not already stored.
                    if(!contains(newEntry) && numberOfEntries != 0)
                    {
                        aNewNode.next = firstNode;
                        firstNode.next = aNewNode;
                        firstNode = aNewNode;

                        result = true;
                    }
                    else
                        result = false;
                }

                return result;      
            }//End add

        public boolean contains(T anEntry){
                boolean found = false;

                while (!found && (firstNode != null))
                {
                    if(anEntry.equals(firstNode.getData()))
                        found = true;
                    else 
                        firstNode = firstNode.getNextNode();
                }

                return found;
            }
    private class Node {

            private T data;
            private Node next;

            private Node (T theData){
                data = theData;
                next = null;
            }

            private Node(T theData, Node nextNode){
                data = theData;
                next = nextNode; 
            }
    } //End Node class
}End LinkedSet
```

In addition this is the test method for add (writing a separate testing app is required and done in a separate main class)

```
private static boolean testAdd(SetInterface<String> aSet, String[] contentsToAdd){

        boolean result = false;

        for (int index = 0; index < contentsToAdd.length; index++)
        {
            aSet.add(contentsToAdd[index]);
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }//End testAdd
```

There are some other methods as well but until I can get the add method working I can't do much with them so I pretty sure the problem is around here somewhere. 
I've looked around the net at similar questions but I still can't see where it is off. Any help is appreciated, I've been messing with it for too long now.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(firstNode == null)
    firstNode = aNewNode;
```

You should return `true` in this case.

```
if(!contains(newEntry) && numberOfEntries != 0)
```

This test doesn't make much sense. It would make more sense the other way round:

```
if(numberOfEntries != 0 && !contains(newEntry))
```

as there is no point in calling `contains()` if there are no entries, but `contains()` already knows that anyway, by virtue of `firstNode` being null if `numberOfEntries` is zero, so it should be just

```
if (!contains(newEntry))
```

NB You aren't maintaining `numberOfEntries`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read all your code thoroughly but there is a mistake here:

```
if(firstNode == null)
        firstNode = aNewNode;
```

it should increment `numberOfEntries`.

Because of that `numberOfEntries` is always zero and add is not working properly

Similarly, you don't maintain `numberOfEntries` in `else` too.

Answer (score 0):

Contains method also having problem, You are changing firstNode reference you should not change that

```
public boolean contains(T anEntry){
                boolean found = false;
                Node ptr = firstNode;
                while (!found && (ptr != null))
                {
                    if(anEntry.equals(ptr.getData()))
                        found = true;
                    else 
                        ptr = ptr.getNextNode();
                }

                return found;
            }
```

Comment: firstNode = firstNode.getNextNode();